# I can't seem to convert a linetext to a number in Qtcreator

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a program that takes `3` user inputs and a calculate button that puts them all into an equation and prints out the answer. The problem I am having right now is that the inputs seem to not be able to convert to numbers and I can't figure out why.

Error reads on line `(int numN0 = QString::number(N0);):`

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QString::number(QString&)'
```

Here's my code:

Header

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_NtButton_clicked();

    void on_N0Button_clicked();

    void on_kButton_clicked();

    void on_tButton_clicked();

    void on_quitButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_5_clicked();

    void on_equation_linkActivated(const QString &link);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    int N;
    int N0;
    int k;
    int t;
};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    /*QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Quit the program!");
    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
    button->show();
    */
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QMessageBox>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_N0Button_clicked()
{
    QString N0 = ui->lineEdit_2->text();
    int numN0 = QString::number(N0);

    if (numN0 < 1000){
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Error","Can't be over 1000");
    }

    if (ui->lineEdit_2->text() > 0)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Error","Can't be under 0");
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_kButton_clicked()
{
    int k = ui->lineEdit_3->text();

    if (QString::number(k) > 1)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Error","Can't be over 1");
    }

    if (ui->lineEdit_3->text() < 0)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Error","Can't be under 0");
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_tButton_clicked()
{
    QString t = ui->lineEdit_4->text();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < t; x++)
    {
        int ans = N*x == N0*10^(k*x);
        ui->equation->setText(QString::number(ans));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
QString N0 = ui->lineEdit_2->text();
int numN0 = N0.toInt();
```

`QString::number(N0)` takes `int` and return `QString`, but you need conversion to `int`. Also you can use `bool ok` if you want to know is conversion was successful.

For example:

```
QString str = "FF";
bool ok;
int hex = str.toInt(&ok, 16);       // hex == 255, ok == true
int dec = str.toInt(&ok, 10);       // dec == 0, ok == false
```

[Information](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt)